# CFMAIL with loop and attachment

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I have a query that gets data for a sales report for a group of stores.

I need to create a PDF of the monthly sales for each store and then email the sales manager the report for his/her store only.

The create PDF part is working fine. It creates a separate report for each store.

When I try to email the report, it sends one report for each record instead of one report for all sales people. EX: If there are 4 people on the report for store #1, the sales manager will get 4 reports instead on 1 report.

**Here is my code: Creating the PDF**

```
     <cfoutput query="data" group="site_name">
     <cfdocument format="pdf" overwrite="yes" fontembed="yes" 
     pagetype="Letter"
     filename="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxsite_name#.pdf" margintop="0.25" 
     marginbottom="0.25" marginleft="0.25" marginright="0.25" 
     backgroundvisible="yes">
     <table width="100%" align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5"
     cellspacing="0"> 
     <tr bgcolor="##e1e8f7">
     <td colspan="8" align="center">Sales Report  -#today#-#site_name#</td>
     </tr>
     <tr align="center">
     <td>Sales Person</td>
     <td>Total Sales</td>
     </tr>
     <cfoutput>
     <tr>
    <td>#firstName# #lastName#</td>
    <td>#totalSales#</td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </table>
    </cfdocument>
    </cfoutput>
```

**CFMAIL**

```
    <cfmail query="data" to="#salesmanageremail#" subject="monthly sales 
    report" 
    type="html">
    <style type="text/css">
    body { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
    </style>
    <body>
    Report attached.
   </body>
   <cfsilent>
   <cfmailparam file="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxsite_name#.pdf">
   </cfsilent>
   </cfmail>
```

How do I email one report per store containing all of the data to each sales manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat your `cfmail` tag as a cfoutput tag.  That includes using the group attribute as you did when creating the pdf.

Alternatively, you can put the `cfmail` tag within the `cfoutput` block you are using to create the pdf.  All things considered, that's the approach I would take.  That way you send the correct file for each site.